# To open links from one div section to another works BUT

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to open links from one `div` section to another (on the same page). I managed to do that and it works (see code below).

BUT... The problem is the content `div`-area (`div`-area where the link-content is shown) is blank for start (when I open the html-file). How can I get e.g. the `m1` content showing in the content-div for start?

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    var aID = $(this).attr('href');
    var elem = $('' + aID).html();
    $('.target').html(elem);
  });
});
```

```css
#m1,
#m2,
#m3,
#m4,
#m5,
#m6,
#m7,
#m8,
#m9 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- SideBar Div ---------------------------------------->
<div id="sideBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#m1">LINK1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#m2">LINK2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#m3">LINK3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Content Div ---------------------------------------->
<div id="mainContent">
  <!-- LINK CONTENET m1 -->
  <div id="m1">
    <p>text content</p>
  </div>
  <!-- LINK CONTENET m2 -->
  <div id="m2">
    <p>text content</p>
  </div>
  <!-- LINK CONTENET m3 -->
  <div id="m3">
    <p>text content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add your html codes by pressing `ctrl+m` keys while asking a new question or editing your own

Comment: u have done #m1 {display:none} it will hide the m1 content, if you want to view then you have to do it as #m1 {display:block}

Comment: Would you provide a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

```js
$('#m1').show();
  $('a[href="#m1"]').addClass('active');
  $('a').on('click',function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    var aID = $(this).addClass('active').attr('href');
    $('.tabcontent').hide(300);
    $(aID).show(300);
  });
```

```css
.active{  color: red;}
#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5, #m6, #m7, #m8, #m9 { display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#m1">m1</a>
<a href="#m2">m2</a>
<a href="#m3">m3</a>
<a href="#m4">m4</a>
<a href="#m5">m5</a>
<a href="#m6">m6</a>

<div id="m1" class="tabcontent">M1 content</div>
<div id="m2" class="tabcontent">M2 content</div>
<div id="m3" class="tabcontent">M3 content</div>
<div id="m4" class="tabcontent">M4 content</div> 
<div id="m5" class="tabcontent">M5 content</div> 
<div id="m6" class="tabcontent">M6 content</div>
```

**Updated** with your html:

```js
$('#m1').show();
  $('a[href="#m1"]').addClass('active');
  $('a').on('click',function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    var aID = $(this).addClass('active').attr('href');
    $('#mainContent .tabcontent').hide();
    $(aID).show();
  });
```

```css
.active{  color: red;}
#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5, #m6, #m7, #m8, #m9 { display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sideBar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#m1">LINK1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m2">LINK2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m3">LINK3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id = "mainContent">
  <div id="m1" class="tabcontent"><p>text content1</p></div>
  <div id="m2" class="tabcontent"><p>text content2</p></div>
  <div id="m3" class="tabcontent"><p>text content3</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly here but somehow it doesn't work on my page... everything should be right but no.. I wonder.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say thanks for the people who aswered, especially for Sathis. Your example helped a lot and I got new ideas for solving the problem. In the end, I came up to this little code-thang and it works fine:

CSS: `#m2, #m3, #m4, #m5, #m6, #m7, #m8, #m9 { display:none;}`

JQuery:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        var aID = $(this).attr('href');
        var elem = $(''+aID).html();
        $('.target').html(elem);
        $('#m1').hide(0);
    });});`

HTML:

```
<!-- LINK DIV -------------------------->
<div id="sideBar">
<ul>
<li><h1><a href="#m1">LINK1</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m2">LINK2</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m3">LINK3</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m4">LINK4</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m5">LINK5</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m6">LINK6</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m7">LINK7</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m8">LINK8</a></h1></li>
<li><h1><a href="#m9">LINK9</a></h1></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id = mainContent>
<div class="target">
</div>

<!-- LINK CONTENET DIV---------------->
<div id="m1"><p>LINK1 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK2 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK3 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK4 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK5 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK6 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK7 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK8 CONTENT</p></div>
<div id="m1"><p>LINK9 CONTENT</p></div>
</div>
```